# Why does overload resolution prefer std::nullptr_t over a class when passing {}?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, overload-resolution, nullptr

The following code prints `nullptr` instead of `empty` ([godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/6b7aPb8a1)):

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class empty { };

#if 1
void f(std::nullptr_t) {
    std::cout << "nullptr\n";
}
#endif

void f(empty) {
    std::cout << "empty\n";
}

int main() {
    f({});
}
```

Disabling the `f(nullptr_t)` variant causes `empty` to be printed. What are the rules C++ is using to select the `nullptr_t` variant over the `empty` variant when both are available?

Comment: See [overload_resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution)

Comment: Why did you expect the `empty` overload? I'd expect an ambiguity.

Comment: Why would the `empty` overload be selected? If it wasn't  specified (as it seems to be), it would be ambiguous.

Comment: @Jarod42 Anything specific on that page I should look out for? I took a look at it and cannot interpret what, specifically, is causing the compiler to prefer one overload over the other.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat there is no ambiguity. If both are present, the compiler selects the `nullptr_t` variant.

Comment: "What are the rules C++ is using" - if you want to know that, then *read the standard* - it is all public.

Comment: I know, I was suprised that you **expected** the `empty` overload to be called.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I think we ordinary mortals sometimes need help with that.

Comment: @JesperJuhl The standard proper is not freely available; it's fairly pricey (~240 US$ at time of comment). The [working drafts](https://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/standards) are freely available, however, and [cppreference](https://cppreference.com) is even better for most use cases.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Initializing `std::nullptr_t` (or any other fundamental type) with `{}` is better because it result in an identity conversion, whereas initializing class types results in a user-defined conversion sequence:

> Otherwise, if the parameter has an aggregate type which can be initialized from the initializer list according to the rules for aggregate initialization ([dcl.init.aggr]), **the implicit conversion sequence is a user-defined conversion sequence** whose second standard conversion sequence is an identity conversion.

- [[over.ics.list] p8](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.list#8)

`empty` is an aggregate type, so this paragraph applies. `std::nullptr_t` is not a class, so the following paragraph applies:

> Otherwise, if the parameter type is not a class:
>
> - (10.1) [...]
> - (10.2) if the initializer list has no elements, **the implicit conversion sequence is the identity conversion.**
> - [...]

- [[over.ics.list] p10](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.list#10)

[[over.best.ics]](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.best.ics) explains which implicit conversion sequence is better, but it should be obvious that an identity conversion beats everything else.